# numpy iterate over two 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

Say I have two matrices:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2, 0.1), np.arange(3, 5, 0.1))
```

And a function, something like:

```
def func(x) :
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2
```

How can I fill a matrix `Z` (of size np.shape(X)), where each entry is formed by calling `func` on the two corresponding values of `X` and `Y`, i.e.:

```
Z[i, j] = func([X[i, j], Y[i, j]])
```

Is there a way without using a double nested for-loop?

Comment: There is a typo `x**[1]` in the code.

Comment: Isn't this just `Z = func([X, Y])`?

Comment: It's best to avoid fractional ranges (like `np.arange(0, 2, 0.1)`) as floating point inaccuracies can cause unpredictable end-points. Use `linspace` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is also works as a vectorized form of function evaluation:

```
import numpy as np
X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(0, 2, 0.1), np.arange(3, 5, 0.1))
def func(x) :
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2

Z = func([X,Y])
```

Answer (score 3):

For given numpy arrays `X` and `Y`, you could just do -

```
Zout = X**2 + Y**2
```

If you are actually constructing `X` and `Y` like that, there is a direct way to get `Z` with [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) and thus avoid `np.meshgrid`, like so -

```
Zout = np.arange(0, 2, 0.1)**2 + np.arange(3, 5, 0.1)[:,None]**2
```

Comment: I did mean for an arbitrary function, but your answer is still really informative. Could you possibly explain what the [:,None] does please?

Comment: @Tom That one is to extend the dimension by introducing a new axis with None. So, in this case, we convert a 1D to a 2D with it. And the idea with extending dimension(s) here is to bring in [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).